I want to copy a selection, including its blank pixels without it being cropped by photoshop
I have tried so many manual and non-manual methods to solve this, i've argued endlessly with chatGPT to try to script a solution (its just doesn't get the context or use the right photoshop methods). This should just be a built in option in Photoshop but regardless of how many posts one can find on the internet about wanting to do this, it's just how it is.
This should be easy even as a script...
Merge my selection into a new layer, figure out if the corners are transparent, add some hot pink (or whatever) pixels to any corner with 100% transparency, copy that into a new document (bonus round: remove those pink pixels)
Please, for the love of my sanity, and the good of any designer who needs to place arbitrary graphics on a grid, help me.
p.s. Yes i'm aware another simple solution is to simply duplicate the doc and crop to my selection, you'd think that'd be easy to script to but evidently not but it IS an alternative method)
p.s.s. the ideal solution would just do this in the background so the artist can just select, hit go, select, hit go, and get on with their day before saving out all the parts with proper file names.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please show us what kind of edit you are trying to achieve, preferably by providing an example image or screenshot. I'm sorry but your explanation of what you are trying to do is a bit odd and currently sounds a bit like an XY problem. You need to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, the actual goal, what it is going to be used for. For example: are you trying to make a selection with rounded corners, or perhaps slice up an image?  TBH, I can't quite work out what you're asking.

any generic copy where you want to have the end result include transparent pixels around the outside.
In this example i did the duplicate document, select, crop method
https://imgur.com/a/uGen5AI

Thanks for the extra info. I've added an answer now.

There's no need to merge any layers or use a script for this. Photoshop has a Slice tool, and Save for Web can automate the saving of the slices for you.

Use the Slice tool C to create slices for each graphic. For example



Do File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)

In the dialog that opens, zoom out so you can see all the slices, and while holding down Shift click to select all the slices. The slices turn from a blue to an orange outline when selected.




Hit Save, and when the Save Optimised As dialog pops up, under the Slices drop down, choose the option for "Selected Slices". And hit Save.


This will save all the slices out as individual files, each including all the transparent pixels.
For more information on the slice tool see the Adobe help pages here and   here

that will definitely work in a limited set of circumstances where there is only one layer in the document you want to take data from, and where the image sections are laid out in a way that's useful for slicing, and ideally you only want to export in a limited set of formats. It does not solve the scenario I have though... as the question asks, i need a solution that will let me select an area with transparent pixels and respect the transparent pixels in that selection (so that it can then be turned into a new layer or document) slices do not fit this criteria.

@tenabraex Using the slice tool and save for web will create new documents.  You can simply open them in Photoshop.  Also this works with multiple layers, not just single layers.  The problem you will have here however is that photoshop doesn't see invisible pixels. For all intents and purposes, they don't exist.  That's why selecting and copy pasting isn't working for you.

@tenabraex - as for laying out the slices in a grid, use something else, such as inDesign, or even Illulstrator.  Each image will have the proper boundary including its invisible pixels, which can be aligned to a grid or guides, etc.

Also note in my example above the slices are all the same size, and are touching each other. However, you can make the slices any size you want, and they don't have to touch. There's no limitation.
